# Rango de Valores en JavaFx JtextField

Tags: javafx, jtextfield

Buenas y gracias de antemano por la ayuda, necesito restringir los valores insertados en un JTextField a >0 y <10 ,preferiblemente cuando el usuario lo termina de escribir en dicho campo, pero no consigo dar con la solución.

Para ello he creado el método handleLimiteNota :

```
       @FXML private void handleLimiteNota(KeyEvent event) {
       // Controlamos el rango de valores del campo txNota
       int c = Integer.parseInt(txNota.getText());
       if (c > 10 || c < 0) {
       System.out.println("error");
       }
```

¿Sería mejor con un listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución muy usada es crear tu propio `TextFormatter`, que restringe la entrada de datos del usuario y evita que el texto llegue al `TextField`, por lo que se logra un rendimiento superior al de lanzar un evento:

```
@FXML
public TextField mytext;

String regex = "10|[1-9]";

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    TextFormatter<String> formatter = new TextFormatter<String>(change -> {
        String text = change.getControlNewText();
        if (!Pattern.matches(regex, text)) {
            change.setText("");
        }
        return change;
    });
    mytext.setTextFormatter(formatter);
}
```

En este caso, la entrada de datos se restringe a partir de una expresion regular (`10|[1-9]`) que acepta el numero 10 ó los numeros entre 1 y 9.

Comment: Genial, mucho más cómodo, solucionado, investigaré más sobre TextFormatter, muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Esto te puede ayudar:

```
    private JTextField jTextFieldName =new JTextField();

    private int limite  = 8;

    jTextFieldName.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

       public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
             if (jTextFieldName.getText().length() == limite)  
             e.consume();
       }

    });
```